# Hide/show sibling-divs instead of using multiple ID's?

Tags: jquery

This dropdown-script works with multiple dropdowns using different ID´s on the divs:

**http://jsfiddle.net/D2kGy/**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    <div id="label_1" class="title">Title</div>

    <div id="drop_1" class="dropdown">
    Content
    </div> <!-- md -->
</div> <!-- ms -->

<br><br><br>

<div class="box">
    <div id="label_2" class="title">Title</div>

    <div id="drop_2" class="dropdown">
    Content
    </div> <!-- md -->
</div> <!-- ms -->
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).on('click',".box, .box div", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var id = this.id.replace('label_', '');
        if ($("#drop_" + id).is(":hidden")) {
            $('.title_active').siblings('[id^=drop_]').hide();
            $('.title_active').removeClass("title_active");
            $("#drop_" + id).show();
            $(this).addClass("title_active");
            $(this).parent().addClass("ms_active");
        } else {
            $("#drop_" + id).hide();
            $(this).removeClass("title_active");
        }
    });
});
```

The "problem" is that there have been more of those dropdowns/selectboxes then expected on the page so using ID´s is getting messy (to many different ID´s).

**Question:** Is there maybe some way of getting this script to work with just display/hide the sibling-divs to the `".box"` div? So no need of unique ID's for every dropdown-box?

Comment: So all you're aiming to do is when you click on the label it'll show, or hide, the dropdowns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can use `.siblings()` to access the element relative to the one that was clicked. This removes the need for any unique IDs, it works based on the classes.

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wDbfB/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).on('click',".box, .box div", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var drop = $(this).siblings('.dropdown');

        if (drop.is(":hidden")) {
            $('.title_active').removeClass("title_active")
                .siblings('.dropdown').hide();
            drop.show();
            $(this).addClass("title_active");
            $(this).parent().addClass("ms_active");
        } else {
            drop.hide();
            $(this).removeClass("title_active");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another script which is working without changing your html markup http://jsfiddle.net/D2kGy/5/ 
Using `.siblings()`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple way to use a class instead of multiple IDs to make the code reusable.

HTML

```
<div class="uthr">
 <div class='cnt'>Hello World</div>
 <div class='cnt2'>Good Bye World</div>
 <a class='hs1' href="#" >Show</a>
</div>

<div class="uthr">
 <div class='cnt'>Hello World</div>
 <div class='cnt2'>Good Bye World</div>
 <a class='hs1' href="#" >Show</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.hs1').click(function() {        
    $(this).siblings('.cnt2').toggle('show');
});
```

CSS

```
.cnt2{display:none;}
```